# Laravel Auth::attempt always return false

Tags: php, laravel

I've tried searching Google and tried several methods. None of them are working though: the `auth::attempt` still returns false. My registration code is below; in my `AuthController` I have:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $datetime = new \DateTime();
    $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $datetime->getTimestamp();

    return User::create([
        'country_id' => 1, // default to malaysia
        'user_name' => $data['user_name'],
        'facebook_id' => null,
        'steam_link' => null,
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'extra_information' => null,
        'remember_token' => null,
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'status_id' => 1, // active
        'is_verified' => false, // false
        'user_type_id' => 2, // normal user
        'account_status_id' => 1, // pending
        'confirmation_code' =>  str_random(30),
        'created_at' => $datetime
    ]);
}

 public function postRegister(Request $request)
 {
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    $user = $this->create($request->all());

    Mail::send('emails.registration_verification', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user)
    {
        $m->from('no-reply@myapps.com', 'www.myapps.com');
        $m->to($user->email, $user->user_name)->subject('Verify your myappsaccount.');
    });

    return view('auth.registration_success')->with('user_name',$user->user_name)->with('email', $user->email);
}

public function emailVerification($confirmation_code)
{
    if (!$confirmation_code)
    {
        return Redirect::route('/errors/500');
    }

    $user = User::whereConfirmationCode($confirmation_code)->first();

    if (!$user)
    {
        return Redirect::route('/errors/500');
    }

    $user->account_status_id = 2; // active
    $user->confirmation_code = null;
    $user->save();

    return view('auth.verification_success')->with('user',$user);
}

public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $userdata = array(
        'email' => $request->email,
        'Password' => $request->password
    );

    if (Auth::attempt($userdata,true)) {
        echo 'test';
    }
    else {
        var_dump($userdata);
    }
}
```

I've hashed my password accordingly, I've also changed the password column from 60 to 255, but still the login fails.

The expected workflow is the user registers, the system sends an email to them for verification. The user clicks the link in the email which will trigger the `emailVerification` method. Once verification is complete, the user should be able to login.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: I'm not certain but have you tried changing the 'Password' key to 'password' (all lowercase)?

Comment: It should definitely be lowercase, and the password column should only be 60 characters long.

Comment: Hi...the password is all lowercase ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your error is here:

```
$userdata = array(
        'email' => $request->email,
        'Password' => $request->password
);
```

The `password` field in your database is lowercase and you're checking for one that starts with an uppercase `P`. Change `'Password' => $request->password` to `'password' => $request->password` and it should work.

Comment: hi, i have change the "Password" to "password", it still failed.

Answer (score 0):

my bad, included the follow code in user model help me solve the problem.

```
public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
```